# How to make an image fill out its parent container?

Tags: flutter

I want my image to fill exactly half of my screen, and in the bottom row i want to add some more widgets. I tried to make the rows spaceAround so that equal space is given. On adding image widget to row, small image was displayed. I added a SizedBox.expand parent to the image and gave the image BoxFit.fill fit, and then the entire image disappeared all together. How do I fix this problem?

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

   final view = Column(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
     children: <Widget>[
       Row(
         children: <Widget>[
           SizedBox.expand(
             child: Image.asset('assets/airb.jpeg'),
           )
         ],
       ),
       Row(
         children: <Widget>[

         ],
       )
     ],
   );

   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text('Image')
     ),
     body:  view,



   );
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it right, from your description, you would like to have an image on the top half of your screen and then some other widgets below it.

Usually when I do things relative to the size of a container (or relative to the screen size), I'm using `LayoutBuilder` which will tell you the size constraints that it has (like maxHeight, maxWidth). One thing tho, be careful with it because sometimes these constraints can be `=infinity` (if you wrap the `LayoutBuilder` inside a ```Row/Column``

Now for your case you can use the following code snippet:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
          // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(height: constraints.maxHeight / 2, color: Colors.red), // replace this with an image

              //Add extra widgets here.
              Text("this will be below image")
            ],
          );
        }));
  }
```

Note, the code is a simple example on how to do the sizing, you will have to add the widgets that you need and customise them :).

Comment: Thanks. This helped! I added the height constraint. but it only filled the entire top half after adding the fit parameter as BoxFit.cover

Comment: @Denise Isn't that the result you've wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you-

```
 class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final view = Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                flex: 5,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Image.asset(
                      "images/pitch.png",
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
            Expanded(
                flex: 5,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[],
                )),
          ],
        );

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Image')),
          body: view,
        );
      }
    }
```